# Angular.js: create regex for a few special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have created an angularjs directive for the unitNo input field to not allow special characters to be typed. I want to created a regex for **only these characters** to be disallowed to be typed on input: **^[<>"&]**. My code is working fine for disallow for this regex but my issue is when i put this regex it disallow other characters too like : **(){}#][**, do you know how to fix this issue?

```
angular.module(ANGULAR_MODULE).directive('unitNo', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.keypress(function (event) {
            var regex = new RegExp("^[<>\"&]+$");
            var str = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (regex.test(str)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            else if (event.keyCode == 91 || event.keyCode == 93 || event.keyCode == 123 || event.keyCode == 125 || event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 41 || event.keyCode == 92 || event.keyCode == 124) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: If you only want to disallow the characters in your regex: `[^<>\"&]+$`. This will not match the characters in the range specified. Any other character would be matched.

Comment: Do you literally mean the individual characters ^, [, <, >, ", &, and ] or is this a regex?

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes i want only these characters to disallow. In my code its working fine users cant type these characters on input. but my issue is when i put this regex there is more characters gone disallow as example "(#}]". what i actually want use can not type these characters on input ^<>\"&

Comment: @idmean this is a regex i want to disallow to user to type only these character on input ^<>\"&

Comment: Can you show me what regex are you using?

Comment: Is this still happening ?

Comment: @RahulSharma yes , this is the regex i'm using. 
new RegExp("^[<>\"&]+$");